# Would be possible to enable syntax highlighting for answers on stackoverflow.com/revisions?

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, revisions-list

### Short story:

Compare the [question revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1642028/10) against the [answer revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1642035/5). Answer revisions have no syntax highlighting.

### Long story:

1. Have a Q&A with some code, for instance [this favorite one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)
2. Now go to [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1642028/revisions) of the **question** and then to the [formatted revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1642028/10) (as in picture below)

   [image]
3. Check the code syntax highlighting - it should be ok
4. Now go to [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1642035/revisions) of the **answer** and then to the [formatted revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1642035/5) (as in picture above)
5. Check the code syntax highlighting - it's not ok, there's no coloring of the code

I know this problem is here for a long time, at least since when I signed up. The syntax highlighting works only for question revisions, not for answers. Could you check and  fix this, if it's not intentional ?

Comment: The syntax highlighting is done based on what tags are on the question. I have a feeling that the tags on the question are not being applied to the answers if it is how you say it is.